# node.js npm generate-license with automatic author name

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate a MIT license file with the author name automatically filled in.

Based on [this example from the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-license#generate-a-license), I am doing this with:

```
gen license:mit
```

Here is the output:

```
[14:10:37] starting generate
[14:10:38] √ running tasks: [ 'license:mit' ]
[14:10:38] starting license
[14:10:38] starting license:mit task
? Author's name?
```

This is prompting for the author's name.

Is there a way to provide the author's name as a CLI input argument? eg. something like:

```
gen license:mit --author="Tom Smith"`
```

I would like to bypass the prompt for the author's name, since I want to generate the license without any prompts.

Is this possible? Or is there a default config file where I can input the author name that should always be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such built in option like `--author` exists, but you could use a workaround and send the author's name to the command:

In bash (thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/338860)), you can do:

```
$ gen license:mit <<< "Tom Smith"
```

or using a pipe:

```
$ printf "Tom Smith" | gen license:mit
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had tried a pipe: `gen license:mit | "Tom Smith"` but it did not work. I had the wrong syntax. Your methods are the answer I was looking for. Many thanks again.